# Detect, delete empty columns and update database in sql, oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have 100 of columns and some of the doesn't have any values inside(they are empty) how can I search for empty columns and delete from table and update database? I tried this query but it doesnt work. It shows 0 rows selected. After selecting how can I update the database?

```
select table_name, column_name 
from all_tab_columns 
where table_name='some_table'  
and column_name is NULL;
```

Thanks,

Comment: you are looking for the column_name as NULL in the dictionary table? and you want to delete or drop the column from the table?

Comment: I am looking for column name which is empty and doesnt have any value and I want to drop it from table..

Comment: please be careful and use only the update the scripts mentioned here

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge! I appreciate that! I used the last updated code and put there my schema name and table name. And the result was 'Gather the printed DDLs, please review it and then proceed to drop')' It didnt drop the columns from my table..

Comment: It wont drop any, I changed. re run, copying the script from here with schema and table name in CAPS.

Answer (score 1):

You are querying a data dictionary view.  It shows *meta-data*, in formation about the database.  This view, ALL_TAB_COLUMNS, shows information for every column of every table (you have privileges on).  Necessarily COLUMN_NAME cannot be null, hence your query returns no rows.

Now what you want to do is query every table and find which columns have no data in them.  This requires dynamic SQL.  You will need to query ALL_TAB_COLUMNS, so you weren't completely off-base.

Because of dynamic SQL this is a programmatic solution, so the results are displayed with DBMS_OUTPUT.

```
set serveroutput on size unlimited
```

Here is an anonymous block: it might take some time to run.  The join to USER_TABLES is necessary because columns from views are included in TAB_COLUMNS and we don't want those in the result set.

```
declare
    dsp varchar2(32767);
    stmt varchar2(32767);
begin
    << tab_loop >>
    for trec in ( select t.table_name
                 from user_tables t )
    loop
        stmt := 'select ';
        dbms_output.put_line('table name = '|| trec.table_name);
        << col_loop >>
        for crec in ( select c.column_name
                             , row_number() over (order by c.column_id) as rn
                      from user_tab_columns c
                      where c.table_name = trec.table_name  
                      and c.nullable = 'Y'
                      order by c.column_id )
        loop
            if rn > 1 then stmt := concat(stmt, '||'); end if;
            stmt := stmt||''''||crec.column_name||'=''||'
                        ||'to_char(count('||crec.column_name||')) ';
        end loop col_loop;
        stmt := stmt || ' from '||trec.table_name;
        execute immediate stmt into dsp;
        dbms_output.put_line(dsp);
    end loop tab_loop;
end;
```

sample output:

```
table name = MY_PROFILER_RUN_EVENTS
TOT_EXECS=0TOT_TIME=0MIN_TIME=0MAX_TIME=0
table name = LOG_TABLE
PKG_NAME=0MODULE_NAME=0CLIENT_ID=0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Any column where the COUNT=0 has no values in it.

Now whether you actually want to drop such columns is a different matter.  You might break programs which depend on them.  So you need an impact analysis first.  This is why I have not produced a program which automatically drops the empty columns. I think that would be dangerous practice.

It is crucial that changes to our database structure are considered and audited.  So if I were ever to undertake an exercise like this I would alter the output from the program above so it produced a script of drop column statements which I could review, edit and keep under source control.

Comment: Thanks I understood what u mean.. but I am new to sql. Please help me with PL/SQL query..